# integrate domain with blogger

Tags: dns, blogger, google-blogger-api

i have a problem with integrate my domain with google blogger

i use CWPContrl panal

it always give me that error

[image]

thats my dns records

[image]

i don't know where the problem

Comment: Is the domain verified in Google Webmasters?

Comment: actually i solved the problem , i got mistake with domain host ,, thanks